# AWS Build Project succeeds even when a command fails in buildspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-codepipeline

I'm using AWS CodeBuild to deploy the function to AWS lambda using serverless-framework.

Here is my buildspec.yml,

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10  
    commands:
      - echo installing Mocha...
      - npm install -g mocha
      - echo installing Serverless...
      - npm install -g serverless
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo running npm install for global project...
      - npm install
      - echo running npm install for each function...
      - folders=src/*
      - for value in $folders;
        do
          echo $value
          npm --prefix $value install $value;
        done
  build:
    commands:
      - sls package
      - serverless deploy --stage $STAGE --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | tee deploy.out
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo done
      # - . ./test.sh
```

The problem is even when the `serverless deploy --stage $STAGE --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | tee deploy.out` command fails, the build project is shown as success by AWS codebuild in the codepipeline.

I want the build status as failure when serverless deploy command fails.

Comment: Can you enable CW logs for CB, and check the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command:

```
- serverless deploy --stage $STAGE --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | tee deploy.out
```

... is not returning a non-zero code on failure which is required to fail the build. The command `tee` is masking the return code from `serverless deploy` as it itself is responding with a '0' return code.

I would recommend to re-write the command as:

```
- serverless deploy --stage $STAGE --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION > deploy.out
- cat deploy.out
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `post_build` **executes whether** `build` fails or succeeds. Thus it does not meter that build fails, `post_build` will run anyway. This is explained in the [build phase transitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/view-build-details.html#view-build-details-phases).

You can rectify this by "manually" checking if `build` failed in `post_build` by checking `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` [env variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html):

- CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING: Whether the current build is succeeding. Set to **0 if the build is failing**, or 1 if the build is succeeding.

Thus in your `post_build` you can check if`CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING == 0` and `exit 1` if is true.

```
  post_build:
    commands:
      - if [[ $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING == 0 ]]; then exit 1; fi
      - echo done
      # - . ./test.sh
```

Comment: @ReyanshKharga Hi. can you `echo $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` and verity its value in `post_build`?